# Function output displaying nothing, Python

Tags: python, function, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a program in Python 3 that turns the DNA codon into an amino acid, however, after inputing the code, I get no error messages, but the function does not display anything after I run the code and type in the DNA code. Ex: ATTGTTTCT, should display ILE VAL SER, I am not getting the ILE VAL SER. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DNA_sequence = input("Enter your DNA sequence below: \n")
DNA = DNA_sequence.upper()
DNA_to_codons = ([DNA[start:start + 3]] for start in range(0, len(DNA), 3))

print('The amino acid chain of your DNA sequence is as follows: \n')
for i in DNA_to_codons:
    if(i=="ATG"): print("MET", end = ' ')
    if(i=="TGA" or i=="TAA" or i=="TAG"): print("END", end = ' ')
    if(i=="TTT" or i=="TTC"): print("PHE", end = ' ')
    if(i=="TTA" or i=="TTG" or i=="CTT" or i=="CTC" or i=="CTA" or i=="CTG"): print("LEU", end = ' ')
    if(i=="ATT" or i=="ATC" or i=="ATA"): print("ILE", end = ' ')
    if(i=="GTT" or i=="GTC" or i =="GTA" or i=="GTG"): print("VAL", end = ' ')
    if(i=="TCT" or i=="TCC" or i=="TCA" or i=="TCG"): print("SER", end = ' ')
    if(i=="CCT" or i=="CCC" or i=="CCA" or i=="CCG"): print("PRO", end = ' ')
    if(i=="ACT" or i=="ACC" or i=="ACA" or i=="ACG"): print("THR", end = ' ')
    if(i=="GCT" or i=="GCC" or i=="GCA" or i=="GCG"): print("ALA", end = ' ')
    if(i=="TAT" or i=="TAC"): print("TYR", end = ' ')
    if(i=="CAT" or i=="CAC"): print("HIS", end = ' ')
    if(i=="CAA" or i=="CAG"): print("GLN", end = ' ')
    if(i=="AAT" or i=="AAC"): print("ASN", end = ' ')
    if(i=="AAA" or i=="AAG"): print("LYS", end = ' ')
    if(i=="GAT" or i =="GAC"): print("ASP", end = ' ')
```

Comment: Use a dictionary like `{'ATG': 'MET', 'TGA': 'END'}` etc.

Comment: Fully agree with @Chris_Rands: Python's dictionaries are one of the most useful objects in this language. Another advice: don't use `i` for your loop variable name if what you are looping over is something else than an integer. It will make your code clearer to use a more meaningful variable name, like `codon`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your third line of code, change

```
DNA_to_codons = ([DNA[start:start + 3]] for start in range(0, len(DNA), 3))
```

to

```
DNA_to_codons = (DNA[start:start + 3] for start in range(0, len(DNA), 3))
```

Each element in `DNA_to_codons` was being yield as a list instead of a string, making `DNA_to_codons` a generator containing lists in your original code, hence the comparisons didn't work as a list (i.e. `["ATT"]`) was being compared to a string (i.e. `"ATT"`).